# how to pass session variable in href

Tags: c#

```
want to pass session of account id through href.. i tried with 
`href="../Profile/Home.aspx?uid=<% =&Session("AccountId")%>"`
```

> but its not working.. help me

Comment: try to get rid of the &? 
Also make sure you have the value for session("accountId")

Comment: what is not working... compiler error or do you get something else as expected as output? just looking at the code you shouldn't have the & after =.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
href="../Profile/Home.aspx?uid=<%= Session["AccountId"] %>"
```

You had an extraneous & in there. Also Session is indexed with [], not ()

Comment: Does that work vice versa?? like `href="../Profile/Home.aspx?<% Session["AccountId"] = 29%>"`

Comment: @william: You should be able to set session variables that way, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: @Ferruccio is it possible to add more session variables through href?  `href="../Profile/Home.aspx?uid=<%= Session["AccountId"] %>&UName=<%= Session["UserName"] %>" `

Comment: Thankyou so much :)